# Defining resource-ref tags on both session bean and entity bean

Tags: ejb, database-connection, jndi, connection-pooling, resource-ref

My application has a CMT session bean invoking a BMP entity bean that uses JDBC queries to perform Database operations.the ejb-jar.xml have resource ref defined at both the session bean definition and the entity bean definition at ejb-jar.xml. is it not sufficient to place the resource references only on session beans rather that having it defined on both session and entity beans ?

Answer (score 0):

The resource-refs in the ejb-jar.xml are only visible within the EJB definition that contains them.

If an EJB is not performing a JNDI lookup of a resource then it will not need the resource-ref.

Comment: Hi Steve , Thanks for your response. If the EJB calls a POJO , are the resource-refs still valid if the resource look up is performed from the POJO class?

Comment: Yes it is still valid. This is because it is executing within the scope of the EJB. An EJB is like a mini container.